# How to manage shopping basket with 10 minute expiration for each Order detail?

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller

I have a website for sponsoring and selling Licence. Some sponsoring area and their quantity are defined (and their price for Non-Exclusive). some of these areas are None-Exclusive and has a price. but some,Exclusive ones, dose not have price and just need for administrator acceptance.

All these order-details, like reservation system, has time limit. If it doesn't accepted by admin or if doesn't pay, it will be removed after 10 minutes. (I don't have any Idea about Admin acceptance and time limit?!)

Whats more I have some other products. these products are license. they don't have time limit and just need to be paid.

Now how can I implement these basket. How to add and remove order details items?

Comment: Where you need to do in Javascript or in back end.

Comment: because other users may have this chance to reserve and buy a sponsoring area .

Answer (score 0):

In your pending orders table, have a date time that the order was created/last updated. If at any time a processing attempt occurs, check the time difference between NOW and when the record was made/updates. If more than 10 minutes, cancel the order

You either do this on c# or the database. Probably easiest in c# using:

```
(DateTime.UtcNow - orderUpdatedDate).TotalMinutes < 10
```